# How can I change the window shadow size for windows in the GNOME shell? 

Tags: gnome, gui, mutter

How can I change the window shadow size for windows in the gnome shell?

I'm trying the shell out and I like it so far. I know it uses mutter rather than compiz so there's no ccsm that I'm used to.

But I understand you can configure almost everything within /usr/share/gnome-shell via css and js. Awesome

Anybody know where the window shadow line is?

Comment: little bump. Is it true that the mutter source needs to be edited for window shadows?

Answer (score 1):

You can only edit the Shell theme via /usr/share/gnome-shell, not the windows.
As far as I know, you must edit the mutter source code, and this might become quite difficult if you don't know programming.

Comment: There is nothing like CCSM (compiz config settings manager) yet for mutter that you know of?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't think there's a CCSM like Mutter settings manager :(

Answer (score 0):

(Not tested)

Edit the theme manually by adding the following to ~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css:

> .window-frame {box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px black;}

Use values to suit :)

Source: https://www.reddit.com/r/gnome/comments/2achwa/tweaking_mutter_window_shadows/

Comment: It makes no difference for me.